# How to select elements between two "h2" except one element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector, nextuntil

so I'm working with a website that is designed like this:

```html
<h2>
  <span id="Explanation"> Explanation </span>
</h2>
<table> ... don't select anything in this table </table>
<a href="https://www.google.com/">hey</a>
<p> What's up? </p>
<p> How's life? </p>
<h2>
  <span id="Transcript"> Transcript </span>
</h2>
<p> Don't select this </p>
```

I want to select everything in between the explanation header and the transcript header using jQuery, but I'm having trouble getting any text at all. My current jQuery to get this is as follows:

```
explanation = "";
explanation = $("h2 #Explanation").nextUntil("h2 #Transcript").text();
```

But right now, I don't select any text at all. Also, I'm not sure about how to get only the a and p text and not the table text. Any help you guys could give me would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector to select `h2` has specific child and use [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to remove specific element from set of selector.

```
$("h2:has(#Explanation)").nextUntil("h2:has(#Transcript)").not("table").text();
```

```js
var explanation = $("h2:has(#Explanation)").nextUntil("h2:has(#Transcript)").not("table").text();
console.log(explanation);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>
  <span id="Explanation"> Explanation </span>
</h2>
<table><tr><td>table</td></tr></table>
<a href="https://www.google.com/">hey</a>
<p> What's up? </p>
<p> How's life? </p>
<h2>
  <span id="Transcript"> Transcript </span>
</h2>
<p> Don't select this </p>
```

Comment: @Musa Nope, `.nextUntil()` return seleced element and `.not()` filter them.

Answer (score 1):

Following excludes the table and maps to array each element's text so you can separate each text block. If no whitespace in the elements then running `text()` on whole collection will leave no separation

```js
var txt = $('#Explanation').parent().nextUntil('h2:has(#Transcript)').not('table').map(function() {
  return $(this).text()
}).get().join(' || ')

alert(txt)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2><span id="Explanation"> Explanation </span></h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>... don't select anything in this table</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<a href="https://www.google.com/">hey</a>
<p>What's up?</p>
<p>How's life?</p>
<h2>
   <span id="Transcript"> Transcript </span>
 </h2>
<p>Don't select this</p>
```

Used `" || "` delimiter in `join()` just to make it obvious where separator is...adjust accordingly